# XMBC select does not work with MK802III and Logitec wireless kb/mousepad - how to resolve?

Tags: 4.0-ice-cream-sandwich

Using Aptoid, I installed XMBC on the MK802III. As per Update 2 found [here](http://xbmc.org/natethomas/2012/12/02/xbmc-12-frodo-beta-2-now-with-android/), it takes a while to load on the first run. The XMBC logo appears, and sometimes the menu shows up.

When the menu does appear, I can use the arrow keys on the Logitec wireless keyboard / mouse pad to move around, however I cannot select any of the menu options with any keys or any of the mouse buttons.

The right mouse button makes a "back" sound, but still nothing.